# Converting numbers contained in Strings to Integers and removing not number values and blank spaces

Tags: ruby, string

I would like to convert a `String` containing multiple numbers so that all those numbers become `Integer`s. That is, I have:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0" # String
" 1,  2, 3,  4, 5   , 6 ,7 ,8  ,9  ,  0" # String (spaces are important)
```

and I would like to have:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] # Array
```

But there is more. If I have:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,e" # String
"  1,  2 , 3   ,  4  ,  5 , a, b,c  , d , e" # String (spaces are important)
```

I would like to have (value that are not numbers are removed):

```
[1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5] # Array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,e".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
"  1,  2 , 3   ,  4  ,  5 , a, b,c  , d , e"
  .split(',')
  .map {|e| e.strip} 
  .find_all {|e| e =~ /(\d)+/ }
  .map {|e| e.to_i}
```